# Microsoft Test Manager (MTM) shared step action recording intermittently not available

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

Action recordings on shared steps in Microsoft Test Manager (2012 Update 3) seem to work only intermittently.  Here's what I'm seeing:

- I create a shared step, with a single parameter.
- I create an action    recording for the shared step.
- I create a new test case, add the    shared step in, and add one other step.  I add a single value for the    shared step parameter.
- I run the test case.
- The test runner shows that there is an action recording for the shared step - by a blue bar next to the shared step: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsDHi.png
- I exit out of the test runner, and then run the test again, and now the shared step appears to not have an action recording: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqzB8.png

It seems to be completely random as to if the shared step knows it has an action recording.  Have others seen this?  Any suggestions on how to remedy?  I've tried it in 2013 Preview, and still get the same results.

Comment: Does the action recording actually work, or is the bar just blue?

Comment: Yes, if the bar is blue, then the action recording will run and work correctly.

Comment: I escalated this issue to my company's Microsoft rep, and got this response today: "It turns out that we have escalated your information to the product group, who has recreated the situation and is working on a fix.  When I hear something back from them I will be sure to contact you."

Comment: Did you ever hear back from MS on this?

Comment: I just followed up with MS yesterday, and still haven't heard back anything of substance.  I'll be sure to post something here when I do.

Comment: @wags1999 did you hear anything from them? since it seems that i have the same problem.

Comment: The final communication from my Microsoft rep was: "According to PG this was a very rare situation which has been corrected and will be available for future releases.  Thank you for bringing it to our attention!"  He didn't provide what release it was planned for.  I can only hope that possibly 2013 Update 1 will include it...

Comment: I have a similiar issue, whenever i cancel an action recording which contains a shared step, the shared steps recording gets deleted and therefore all actionrecordings which contains this step get deleted!